# Can't get flash to work

Tags: flash

I feel like I have tried everything, but I also have no idea what I'm doing, so I hope you guys can help me out. I have installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras from the Software center. Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 is listed in the Firefox Plugins, but flash does not work in my browser. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Ive tried running:

```
sudo apt-add-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner”
```

in terminal, but it returns

```
Error: need a single repository as argument
```

I'm a complete noob to any of this, so help is much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: First of all, why are you adding an external repository? Second, are you trying to use Flash in Chromium? Or you mean that Firefox sees Flash... but it doesn't run it?

Comment: Which site doesn't work? It may have DRM, or not really be using flash...